# Azure project - which subfolders/files should be checked into version control?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a small Azure project (using Visual Studio 2015). I have created a Azure Cloud service project with only one webjob. Inside the cloud service project, vs2015 created some subfolders like 'csx', 'ecf', 'XXXXXXXXContent', 'Profile', 'rcf'.

I wonder whether I should checkin these subfolders and the files inside. Of course, the 'Release' and 'Debug' folder inside these subfolders won't be checked in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Folders with lowercases are generated during compilation and publish process.

- csx: Packaged files which ready to be published. But as of Azure Tools v1.4, it is no longer generated unless you run in emulator. [This blog post](http://www.andrewthompson.co/2011/12/deploying-packages-to-azure-compute.html) describes in detail.
- rcf: which stands for `Role Content Files`. You already has `---WorkerRoleContent` and rcf is generated through build configuration. You can think it as a kind of *bin folder for contents*.
- ecf: It is generated folder for diagnostics settings depended on `diagnostics.wadcfgx' file. The file is specific for publish settings, so you should not include it in source control.

Overall, all three folders are automatically generated for publishing and they should not be added to source control.

However, `Profile` and `----Content` folders are required to maintain your publish settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate!